# CRM 2013, Copy the order products from the last sales order

Tags: javascript, html, copy, dynamics-crm

How can i add the last order Products, to the newly created sales order products.
I  have retrieved all my products from my last order, but I dont know how to add them to the current sales/salesOrderDetail.

I need to do this in javascript, i can not use Csharp code.
the function retrieveproducts() is working well, the function retrievedProductsCallBack(data) has to create/copy the retrieved products on the order form but I don't know how to do it.. any suggestionns and or hulp is welcome.

**// Code example**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var salesOrderID, clientId;
    //this function is used to get products from last order
    function RetrieveProducts() {
        var odataQuery;
        var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
        clientId = oMyObject.customerid;
        salesOrderID = oMyObject.salesorderid;

        var entitySchemaName = "SalesOrder";
        if (document.getElementById("checkID").checked == true) {
            odataQuery = "?$top=1&$select=order_details/IsPriceOverridden,order_details/IsProductOverridden,order_details/ProductId,order_details/SalesOrderId,order_details/UoMId&$orderby=CreatedOn desc&$expand=order_details&$filter=CustomerId/Id eq guid'" + clientId + "'";
        }
        else {
            odataQuery = "?$top=1&$select=order_details&$orderby=CreatedOn desc&$expand=order_details&$filter=CustomerId/Id eq guid'" + clientId + "'";
        }

        SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords(entitySchemaName, odataQuery, retrievedProductsCallBack, function (error) { alert(error.message); }, function () { });
    }

    function retrievedProductsCallBack(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data[0].order_details.results.length ; i++) {
           var rec = data[0].order_details.results[i];
           var product = rec.ProductId;

           var product = {};

            //Set ohter required attrbitues of products
           product.SalesOrderId = salesOrderID;
           product.ProductId = rec.ProductId;
           product.Quantity = rec.Quantity;


            //create quote product
           SDK.REST.createRecord(product, "SalesOrderDetail", function () { }, function (error) { alert(error.message); }, function () { });
        }
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you change

```
product.SalesOrderId = salesOrderID;
```

to

```
product.SalesOrderId = {Id: salesOrderID, LogicalName: "SalesOrder"};
```

Because `SalesOrderId` is an entity reference.